# (Java + Slick) How to rotate the Graphics (g) around the X-Axis?

Tags: java, lwjgl, isometric, slick

I already tried it by using `GL11.glRotatef(45, 1, 0, 0)`, but the result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: `GL11.glRotatef(45, 1, 0, 0)` corresponds to 45 degrees about the x axis

Comment: oh, you're right. thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just want to tell you that I actually found a solution:

The trick was to set the `near` & `far` values via `GL11.glOrtho(...)` to a higher value, so the "space" for the drawn "things" on the z-axis is enough. For me, I chose 10000 & -10000.

Hope it helps someone else, too. `:)`